# Making Dijkstra's algorithm account for return travel time

Tags: algorithm, tree, dijkstra

so the question goes as follows: An unweighted tree is provided to me and allows me to start at any node, im expected to visit only certain nodes that ive been provided in an array. My goal is to find the amount of time it takes to travel to every node desired. Each edge takes a single minute to travel over.

I have already attempted to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in order to begin at a node I want to visit and attempt to form a shortest path from there. 
but my problem is that although a solution is provided it may not be the most efficient one as I do not know how to force Dijkstra's algorithm to account for traveling over the same edge twice.
[image: tree]

An example of this problem being in the image above. Assuming that I desired to visit nodes[90,50,20,75] and I started at node 90 and traversed to node 50 then to node 20 how would i make Dijkstra's algorithm account for the return travel time to node 50 before reaching node 20?

Comment: Trees have the advantage that the paths between any two nodes are unique. So you don't actually need a path finding algorithm. Btw, Dijkstra makes only sense on weighted graphs. For unweighted graphs, BFS is simpler and usually faster. Is the start and/or end node fixed?

Comment: @NicoSchertler no sir, the start and end nodes are up to me, although i understand that the paths between any 2 nodes will be unique, my solution is suppose to account for the total amount of time to visit each node(assuming they were all stores and i was a human being who could start walking at any node i wanted to and that each edge took 1 minute to walk over), and i'm unsure about how my program is suppose to know when to go back over the same edge? thank you for your time

Comment: I don't have a complete algorithm, just an observation: Assume you are at a node with a number of subtrees. If you descend into one of the subtrees, you should return to the initial node only when all target nodes in that subtree have been visited. At most one subtree is allowed to not return to the initial node (the subtree with the end node). Therefore, it does not matter in which order you traverse the other subtrees. So, a divide-and-conquer approach might work. Btw, this is a Hamiltonian path, which is NP-hard on general graphs. But it looks as if it might be easier on trees.

Comment: To simplify things, you could calculate a cycle (start node = end node). I.e., you will always return to the initial node and can treat all subtrees equally. After you found the cycle, remove the longest path segment.

Comment: @NicoSchertler that likely wouldn't work as I do not need to return to or Start from a single point so I could remove the 2 longest path segments, but your idea in itself of having all nodes return to a single one won't produce the most optimal solution as subtrees may share a single node, meaning that the switch to different subtrees can occur before the initial node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me elaborate on my comments: First, we will fix an arbitrary root in the tree, such that the tree is rooted (maybe you already have a rooted tree). Then, the first step is finding a minimum length cycle that starts at the root and ends at the root and passes through all desired nodes.

This can be done in a divide-and-conquer approach. If you are at any node, you can check if you need to include that node in the path. If so, you do. Then, for every subtree, simply use the same approach and extend the path if necessary. Finally, make sure that the sub path returns to the current subtree's root (code follows).

After you found the cycle, you need to remove the longest sub path such that you end up with a non cyclic path. This can be done in linear time by just walking through the cycle. In my implementation, I had the cycle extraction emit not only the sequence of nodes but also a flag that determines if the path simply passes through a node (and does not visit the node). Therefore, this step simply finds the path segment between any two nodes that are actually visited.

There is still one step missing that is necessary in order to assert optimality. But let me show you the code up to this point. I have implemented it in JavaScript because you can just run it on SO. The implementation is aimed at understandability and not efficiency.

```js
//the tree from your example
var tree = { value: 90, children: [{ value: 50, children: [{ value: 20, children: [{ value: 5 }, { value: 25 }] }, { value: 75, children: [{ value: 66 }, { value: 80 }] }] }, { value: 150, children: [{ value: 95, children: [{ value: 92 }, { value: 111 }] }, { value: 175, children: [{ value: 166 }, { value: 200 }] }] }] };

var nodesToVisit = [90, 50, 20, 75];
//var nodesToVisit = [92, 111, 166];

function findCycle(treeNode, nodesToVisit) {
 var subPath = [];
 var currentNodeIncluded = false;
 if(nodesToVisit.indexOf(treeNode.value) != -1) {
  //this node should be visited
  subPath.push({node: treeNode, passThrough: false});
  currentNodeIncluded = true;
 }
 
 //find the subpath for all subtrees
 if(treeNode.children) {
  for(var i = 0; i < treeNode.children.length; ++i) {
   var subTreePath = findCycle(treeNode.children[i], nodesToVisit);
   if(subTreePath.length > 0) {
    if(!currentNodeIncluded) {
     subPath.push({node: treeNode, passThrough: true});
     currentNodeIncluded = true;
    }   
    //if we need to visit this subtree, merge it to the current path
    subPath = subPath.concat(subTreePath);
    subPath.push({node: treeNode, passThrough: true}); //go back to the current node
   }
  }
 }
 
 return subPath;
}

function removeLongestPassThroughSegment(cycle) {
 var longestSegmentStart = -1;
 var longestSegmentEnd = -1;
 
 //the start of the current pass-through segment between non-pass-through nodes
 var currentStart = -1;
 var segmentLengthAtStart = -1;
 for(var i = 0; i < cycle.length; ++i) {
  if(!cycle[i].passThrough) {
   //we have found a node that we need to visit
   if(currentStart != -1) {
    var length = i - currentStart;
    if(length > longestSegmentEnd - longestSegmentStart) {
     longestSegmentStart = currentStart;
     longestSegmentEnd = i;
    }
   } else
    segmentLengthAtStart = i;
   currentStart = i;
  }
 }
 
 //check the path segment that wraps around
 if(cycle.length - currentStart + segmentLengthAtStart > longestSegmentEnd - longestSegmentStart) {
  longestSegmentStart = currentStart;
  longestSegmentEnd = segmentLengthAtStart;
 }
 
 //build the final path by cutting the longest segment
 var path = [];
 var i = longestSegmentEnd;
 do {
  path.push(cycle[i]);
  i++;
  if(i >= cycle.length)
   i = 0;
 } while(i != longestSegmentStart);
 path.push(cycle[longestSegmentStart]);
 return path;
}

function printPath(path) { 
 for(var i = 0; i < path.length; ++i)
  if(path[i].passThrough)
   console.log("Pass through " + path[i].node.value);
  else
   console.log("Visit " + path[i].node.value);
}

var cycle = findCycle(tree, nodesToVisit);
console.log("Cycle:");
printPath(cycle);

var path = removeLongestPassThroughSegment(cycle);
console.log("Final Path:");
printPath(path);
```

You will find that this code already finds the optimal solution and prints:

```
Final Path:
Visit 90
Visit 50
Visit 20
Pass through 50
Visit 75
```

Even for a more challenging set of desired nodes, this gets to the optimal path (`var nodesToVisit = [92, 111, 166];`):

```
Final Path:
Visit 92
Path through 95
Visit 111
Pass through 95
Pass through 150
Pass through 175
Visit 166
```

Now the essential thing that makes this find the optimal solution is that the path segment that is cut in the end is actually the longest possible path segment. This is not necessarily the case in the above code because you are free to choose the order in which you process subtrees and if you are at a node that should be visited, you are free to put the actual visit (in contrast to pass-throughs) anywhere between the visited subtrees.

In order to do so, find the distance between all desired nodes (which can be done efficiently on a tree). The pair with the largest distance will be the start and end node. Hence, you need to make sure that their visits in the cycle occur subsequently (i.e. there is no other node visited between them). You can do this by enforcing specific visited nodes at the beginning and end of the path segments returned from your recursive calls. For example, let the recursive call also return if the sub path contains a start or end node. And in the calling function, put those sub paths in the correct order. This would also simplify the `removeLongestPassThroughSegment()` function since you already know what the longest path-through segment is.

Comment: I see what you've done here and its great and all just I am not using a binary tree, the image provided was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: The algorithm does not assume a binary tree. It just assumes a rooted tree. And you can turn any tree into a rooted tree by fixing an arbitrary node as the root.